# How do I send UDP packets at a specified rate in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, networking, udp

I'm writing a program that implements the RFC 2544 network test. As the part of the test, I must send UDP packets at a specified rate.

For example, I should send 64 byte packets at 1Gb/s. That means that I should send UDP packet every 0.5 microseconds. Pseudocode can look like "[Sending UDP packets at a specified rate](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.programmer/Sending-UDP-packets-at-a-specified-rate)":

```
while (true) {
    some_sleep (0.5);
    Send_UDP();
}
```

But I'm afraid there is no `some_sleep()` function in Windows, and Linux too, that can give me 0.5 microseconds resolution.

Is it possible to do this task in C++, and if yes, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Does it need to send 1 packet every 0.5 us or can it send pxbmcackets as fast as possible and then wait until one second has passed?

Comment: Yes, I need to send 1 packet every 0.5 us, non-uniform flow of packets can be done separately as recommended (but not required) part of the RFC 2544 test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

- Implement your own sleep by busy-looping using a high-resolution timer such as windows QueryPerformanceCounter
- Allow slight variations in rate, insert Sleep(1) when you're enough ahead of the calculated rate. Use timeBeginPeriod to get 1ms resolution.

For both approaches, you can't rely on the sleeps being exact. You will need to keep totals counters and adjust the sleep period as you get ahead/behind.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful, but I doubt it's directly portable to anything but Windows. [Implement a Continuously Updating, High-Resolution Time Provider for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx) by Johan Nilsson.

However, do keep in mind that for packets that small, the IP and UDP overhead is going to account for a large fraction of the actual on-the-wire data. This may be what you intended, or not. A very quick scan of RFC 2544 suggests that much larger packets are allowed; you may be better off going that route instead. Consistently delaying for as little as 0.5 microseconds between each `Send_UDP()` call is going to be difficult at best.

Comment: To add to Michael's observation, in addition to the 28 bytes of overhead due to the TCP/UDP headers, you will also have 38 additional octets of overhead due to ethernet framing. As a result, the actual bytes going out on the wire are 38+28+64=130 bytes. Furthermore, your actual transmission rates will depend on the loading on the ethernet you're using. What does this all mean? Be careful.

Comment: RFC 2544 specifies a 64 byte *Ethernet frame size* (for the purpose of testing the minimum allowable frame size). That means (18 byte payload + 8 byte udp header + 20 byte IP header + 14 byte Ethernet header + 4 byte FCS) + 20 byte IFG+preamble+SOF = 84 bytes or 672 bits => 672 ns at GbE rate.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

To transmit 64-byte Ethernet frames at line rate, you actually want to send every 672 ns. I think the only way to do that is to get really friendly with the hardware. You'll be running up against bandwidth limitations with the PCI bus, etc. The system calls to send one packet will take significantly longer than 672 ns. A sleep function is the least of your worries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the minimum packet size that I can send without being friendly with hardware?

Comment: Well, *it depends*. If you're trying to do this in software, you're involving a lot of resources (bus/cpu/interrupt handlers/etc) that are shared with other processes that you don't have direct control of. The best way to know for a given system is to test. You could send packets in a loop and count how many were sent over a few minute period. Based on packet size, determine how close to line rate you were. Adjust the packet size and try again. Do a bunch of different runs; you'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You guess you should be able to do it with `Boost Asio`s timer function. I haven't tried it myself, but I guess that `deadline_timer` would take a `boost::posix_time::nanosec` as well as the `boost::posix_time::second`

Check out an example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-gnulib@gnu.org/msg17746.html) a native Windows implementation of `nanosleep`. If GPL is acceptable you can reuse the code, else you'll have to reimplement.